# Designing a web form with default and custom values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

The web form I'm working on right now is the electronic version of a contract. The users want to have default values for a large number of the fields to keep wording consistent. However, they also want to be able to enter a custom value or select multiple values for some of the fields. I'm finding that the presentation layer is bleeding into the backend quite heavily and wondering if anyone has some tips on how to go about designing an application like this?

EDIT: I wanted to try and keep from going into the specifics because there is a large amount of business logic in it. But basically I have a form with about 20 fields in it. 3 of the fields have select boxes with multiple options in them. These are the `default` values I was talking about. But the user also wants to be able to add a "one off" type value to the select. This represents a specific term in the contract that isn't used enough to be valuable as a default. My issue is that I'm storing the default values in the database because the users want to be able to add and remove these defaults at will. Its not just a standard data capture screen.

Comment: Can you give some examples of "the presentation layer is bleeding in the the backend quite heavily"?

Comment: Without information on how exactly you are currently architected it's going to be impossible to suggest a solution.  There are a lot of variables here.

Comment: Yes I'm aware there are a ton of variables. My question is how to go about storing data from an application where there are "default" values as well as "entered" values. The logic for determining which is which is getting mixed into the display of the data. I wish I could post the code and it would be quite obvious that it is ugly. But I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

- tblRecord (RecordID, SomeFieldID, CustomText)
- tlkpSomeField (SomeFieldID, SomeFieldText)

It sucks, but that is actually a pretty common solution.  You can use the CustomText only when the Record shows that SomeFieldID is null.  Your data layer will abstract all of that away, so it will be clean.  You can also store your default value as the first value in the tlkp table.

```
tlkpSomeField
1 Default Value
2 value1
3 value2
4 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, without knowing you or your domain, you have problems with storing both *default* and *chosen* value, you sort of get redundant data in the database.
It feels wierd to store the default flag with the chosen item with the freetext when lots of it is just user stuff.  Sort of.

My thoughts/recommendations are:

Default value doesn't have any business value so don't store it as users' choice.  Just store what the user chose/freetext.

Or does it Mean something that the user chose default?  Then there is business value to it and you should store the value/text the user chose and a tick that it happened to be the default value.

Or I might have misunderstood you totally...

Comment: I think you are kind of on the right track. It does matter when they choose a default value. My issue is in the database I'm storing the ID for that default value instead of the actual text, but when they enter their own text there is no ID. So I end up storing data for the same field in two separate fields on the backend.

Comment: Storing redundant values sucks but one has to be pragmatical too so don't worry too much about it.  Skip storing the ID of the default value, just a boolean that it was default.  Unless the default value changes and there is business value to it.  Then you have the "correct" solution already.  Read the text field when you want the text representation and the ID for when you want the default value for the cases the user chose default.